# Unable to get Temporary Token with Directus v8 API

Tags: php, api, directus

I am using the latest Directus v8 release. I installed it and used it to design my schema and everything seems to be ok, but when I try to get a temporary token to authenticate a user I am getting a strange error about not being authorized, at the same time that the AUTH endpoint doesn't require previously authorized users (obviously).

- My Directus installation is located at htdocs/slotspanel
- Its URL is http://127.0.0.1/slotspanel
- The user's credentials are double-checked, they are correct
- I am using XAMPP with the latest PHP7
- mod_rewrite is enabled

I am trying to authenticate the user with the following script

```
<?php

$data = array(
    'email'      => 'user@mail.com',
    'password'    => 'UserPasswordHere'
);

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => json_encode( $data ),
        'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                    "Accept: application/json\r\n"
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create( $options );
$result = file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1/slotspanel/auth/authenticate", false, $context);
$response = json_decode($result);

echo $response;

?>
```

And I'm getting the following error

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://127.0.0.1/slotspanel/auth/authenticate): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized in C:\xampp_new\htdocs\anotherdomain\index2.php on line 18
```

Error log

```
[2020-06-18 13:36:29] api[auth].ERROR: Directus\Exception\UnauthorizedException: Unauthorized request in C:\xampp_new\htdocs\src\helpers\app.php:287
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp_new\htdocs\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(518): Directus\{closure}
#1 C:\xampp_new\htdocs\src\core\Directus\Application\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware.php(71): Slim\App->__invoke
#2 [internal function]: Directus\Application\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware->__invoke
#3 C:\xampp_new\htdocs\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\DeferredCallable.php(57): call_user_func_array
#4 [internal function]: Slim\DeferredCallable->__invoke
#5 C:\xampp_new\htdocs\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(70): call_user_func
#6 C:\xampp_new\htdocs\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(117): Slim\App->Slim\{closure}
#7 C:\xampp_new\htdocs\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(392): Slim\App->callMiddlewareStack
#8 C:\xampp_new\htdocs\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(297): Slim\App->process
#9 C:\xampp_new\htdocs\src\core\Directus\Application\Application.php(161): Slim\App->run
#10 C:\xampp_new\htdocs\slotspanel\index.php(5): Directus\Application\Application->run [] []
```

Comment: Add `ignore_errors` with value `true` to your context options, then file_get_contents will still return you the response body, even in case of errors. Check what that contains then, if there’s a more detailed error message/description in there.

Answer (score 1):

This was asked and subsequently resolved on GitHub: https://github.com/directus/directus/discussions/2757#discussioncomment-27908

The request URL above `http://127.0.0.1/slotspanel/auth/authenticate` was missing the project in the path. In this particular case, it was supposed to be `http://127.0.0.1/slotspanel/slotspanel/auth/authenticate`