# Unable to make POST call to authenticate with DIRECT US CRM vis Postman

Tags: directus

I am trying to authenticate via postman to get a token. The postman keeps returning

```
{
    "error": {    
    "code": 1,    
    "message": "Not Found"    
    }
}
```

This is my `POST` url: `localhost:8080/:cabellsdata/auth/authenticate` and in my BODY (raw) I have my email and password exactly as stated in docs.

When I do a `GET: localhost:8080/:CabellsData/collections/:journalytics`, it does work. So why is my `POST` not working. Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZc19.png)

Comment: I solved it via this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62448517/unable-to-get-temporary-token-with-directus-v8-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to delete that `:` in the project section of your API URL.

Answer (score -1):

I have PATCH request to update user:
http://localhost:8055/users/98f6c2b1-3d1b-4c29-bf29-6d4596bd26dc

and REST call:
{
"title": "newTitle",
"status": "draft"
}

but it always throw dont have permission to access this.